# How to create non sequence date when i use fill handle

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I entered date in my google spreadsheet example 25/10/2022, then I want to use fill handle to copy that date in the column but the date automatically increasing , like 26/10/2022, 27/10/2022. and i don't need that.

I was expecting to copy same date in the column

Comment: you can just enter `=DATE(year,month,day)` in you cell and then fill the rest of the column

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
="25/10/2022"
```

or lock it down like:

```
=$A$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try holding down Ctrl on the keyboard whilst dragging using the fill handle to override the default 'smart filling' behaviour with simple copying instead.